# Python-Tkinter. como fechar uma janela usando o código e não o botão fechar?

Tags: python, tkinter, interface

existe alguma forma de fechar a janela criada (`container = Tk()`) sem ser pelo botão fechar? queria criar por código, exemplo: uma tela de login, quando o login é efetuado, a tela de login se fecha e abre o programa com as funcionalidades criadas.

Comment: Utilize `container.destroy()`.
Essa pergunta foi feita no [S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110923/how-do-i-close-a-tkinter-window).

Answer (score 1):

Voce pode usar :

```
container.destroy()
```